# Magento 2: how to Add New Table in database

Tags: magento2

Magento2:how to Add New Table in database using code.

Comment: While asking a question, try to elaborate more about your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add installshema for that like below i have added.

```
<?php
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
namespace <vendor>\<module>\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
/**
 * Description of InstallSchema
 *
 * @author dharmendra
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * 
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('<<tablename>>')
        )->addColumn(
            'faq_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Faq Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'product_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false],
            'Product Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'product_name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'Product Name'
        )->addColumn(
            'name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'Name'
        )->addColumn(
            'email',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'Email'
        )->addColumn(
            'question',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'Question'
        )->addColumn(
            'status',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
            'Status'
        )->addColumn(
            'answer_name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'Name of Answerer'
        )->addColumn(
            'answer',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'Answer'
        )->addColumn(
            'answer_status',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
            'Answer Status'
        )->addColumn(
            'creation_time',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            [],
            'Creation Time'
        )->addColumn(
            'creation_time',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            [],
            'Creation Time'
        )->addColumn(
            'answer_time',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            [],
            'Answer Time'
        )->addForeignKey(
            $installer->getFkName(
                '<<tableName>>',
                'product_id',
                'catalog_product_entity',
                'entity_id'
            ),
            'product_id',
            $installer->getTable('catalog_product_entity'),
            'entity_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        )->setComment(
            'Product Faq table.'
        );

        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

change field as per your requirement.